# queryselector must be an object mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I try post data in db but I get this error `queryselector must be an object mongodb`. Here is my code

models
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

```
exports.register = function(val,cb) {
    var email = val['email'];
    var password = val['password'];
    var user  = val['user'];
    MongoClient.connect(//url connect to db  ,function(err,db){
        if(err)
            cb(null,{result:false,message:err});
        db.collection('user').findOne(email,function(err,user){
            if(err)
                cb(null,{result:false,message:err});
            if(user){
                cb(null,{result:false,message:'Email already exists'});
            }else{
                db.collection('user').insert(user,function(err){
                    if(err)
                        cb(null,{result:false,message:err});
                    cb(null,{result:true,message:'Success'});
                })
            }
        })
    });
};
```

controller

```
var express= require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var user = require('../models/register');

router.post('/',function(req,res) {
    var val =[];
    val['email'] = req.body.email;
    val['password'] = req.body.password;
    val['user']={
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    }

    user.register(val,function(err,data){
        if(err)
            console.log(err)
        res.json(data);
    })

});

module.exports = router;
```

I try change to `val={}` but not work too . Where is my wrong? Please help me

Comment: This is wrong `db.collection('user').findOne(email, `
It should be   `db.collection('user').findOne({'email':'whatever-u wanna find'},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be..

```
 exports.register = function(val,cb) {
        var email = val['email'];
        var password = val['password'];
        var user  = val['user'];
        MongoClient.connect(//url connect to db  ,function(err,db){
            if(err)
                cb(null,{result:false,message:err});
            db.collection('user').findOne({email:email},function(err,user){
                if(err)
                    cb(null,{result:false,message:err});
                if(user){
                    cb(null,{result:false,message:'Email already exists'});
                }else{
                    db.collection('user').insert(user,function(err){
                        if(err)
                            cb(null,{result:false,message:err});
                        cb(null,{result:true,message:'Success'});
                    })
                }
            })
        });
    };
```